# Building multiple android apps via script does not trigger Resolving Android Dependencies

Tags: unity, android, build-process

I have a Unity Project which builds a number of smartphone android apps

Anytime I need to build an app I have a script (SetupApp) that move a bunch of assets in the Resources folder and changes the package name.

As far as I understood changing the package name triggers the tedious process of “Resolving Android Dependencies”, because all the various libraries in Plugins/Android need to be recompiled.

So far so good.

Recently I tried to create a multi-builder, basically it’s a script (MultiBuilder) that takes all the applications that need to be created and, before each, calls SetupApp and then calls  BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer

My issue is that when MultiBuilder calls SetupApp the “Resolving Android Dependencies” is not triggered, creating all the app with the same (wrong) dependencies.

Some thoughts:
Is there a way to force by script the “Resolving Android Dependencies”  process?
Is there a way to wait for the resolving process to be finished and the continue the building process?
Is there a better way to do so?

This goes really beyond my understanding of Unity, any help is very welcome.

Thanks